Image Not Shrinking with max-width in CSS: Why Does It Behave Differently from Div?
I have the following <div> in my HTML:
html
<div id="mydiv">This is a div.</div>

The CSS for this <div> is:
css
#mydiv {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

This makes the <div> responsive. When I resize the browser window to less than 500px wide, the <div> shrinks to fit the window size.
I also have the following <img> element in my page:
html
<img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="Nature Image">

The CSS for this image is:
css
img {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

However, the image is not responsive. When I reduce the window size to less than 500px wide, the image does not shrink and instead causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear.
Why does the image not behave like the <div> when both elements have the max-width property? Why do the <div> and <img> elements behave differently?
Note
I know I can make my image responsive by adding width: 100% CSS rule to the img tag, but I'm just wondering why different behavior is observed in the two cases.
Please don't mark this question as duplicate of Max-width on img prevents image from shrinking
There is no reasonable explanation given for this.

It is a duplicate - "You need to give the div an explicit width (e.g. ˋ100%ˋ), otherwise it will use the actual width of the image (implicit ˋwidth: autoˋ) as a reference, which could be more than ˋ100%ˋ:"

Couldn't understand what you meant... I have no issue with div but img.

MDN Reference " is a replaced element; it has a display value of inline by default, but its default dimensions are defined by the embedded image's intrinsic values"

div have a default width of 100%, images have a default width of whatever the width of the image actually is. You have to override that default width if you want the image to shrink.

I got it now. The <img>, unlike <div>, does not become responsive simply by applying the max-width property, because <div> is a block-level element, which by default takes up the full width available and it naturally scales with the width of the parent container.
The <img> is a replaced element, meaning it has intrinsic dimensions (its own width and height).
